# a problem with TimeWindow.getStart() in Flink DataStream API

Tags: java, apache-flink

When I use ProcessWindowFunction like follow:

```
    private static class pwf
        extends ProcessWindowFunction<String, Tuple3<String, String,String>, Tuple, TimeWindow> {//IN, OUT, KEY, W
    public void process(Tuple key,
                        Context context,
                        Iterable<String> elements,
                        Collector<Tuple3<String, String,String>> out) {
        String res = elements.iterator().next();
        out.collect(new Tuple3<String,String,String>(String.valueOf((context.window().getStart())),(String)((Tuple1)key).f0, res));
    }
}
```

I got a start time like this: 1691580000, 1691640000, but I cant understand this formaion, is there anyone could give me some advise? any answer will be great appreciate！

and the whole code maybe help:

```
DataStream<RawLogGroupList> sourceStream = env.addSource(new FlinkLogConsumer<RawLogGroupList>(deserializer, configProps));
        DataStream<Tuple3<String,String,String>> resStream = sourceStream
                .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<RawLogGroupList, RawLog>() {
                    @Override
                    public void flatMap(RawLogGroupList value, Collector<RawLog> out) throws Exception {
                        for (RawLogGroup logGroup : value.getRawLogGroups()) {
                            for (RawLog log : logGroup.getLogs()) {
                                out.collect(log);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setParallelism(flatmapParallelism)
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<RawLog>(Time.seconds(30)) {
                    @Override
                    public long extractTimestamp(RawLog element) {
                        return element.getTime()*1000;
                    }
                }).setParallelism(mapParallelism)
                .map(new MapFunction<RawLog, Tuple3<String,String,Long>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple3<String,String,Long> map(RawLog value) throws Exception {
                        Map<String,String> contents = value.getContents();
                        return new Tuple3<>(
                                contents.getOrDefault("logtime","nullFromMap"),
                                contents.getOrDefault("method","nullFromMap"),
                                Long.valueOf(contents.getOrDefault("latency","0"))
                        );
                    }
                }).setParallelism(mapParallelism)
                .keyBy(1)
                .timeWindow(Time.seconds(60))
                .aggregate(new Med(),new pwf())
                .setParallelism(aggregateParallelism)
            .returns(Types.TUPLE(Types.STRING,Types.STRING,Types.STRING));
```

Answer (score 0):

These numbers are timestamps.

Flink supports different notions of time; in particular *processing time* and *event time* (and also *ingestion time*). Processing time is the system time when the events are being processed. Event time refers to timestamps encoded in the events.

If you are working with processing time, then these will be unix timestamps in milliseconds, just like what is returned from `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

If you are working with event time, then the timestamps are just numbers, and they have whatever meaning your application associates with them, though typically they are also encoded as milliseconds since the epoch (just as with `System.currentTimeMillis()`).

In your case these appear to be unix timestamps in seconds, but the dates are in 2023, which seems odd. 1691580000 is 8/9/2023 at 1:20:00 PM.

If these timestamps don't make sense, it could be that there's a problem with your [timestamp assigner](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#assigning-timestamps).

See the documentation for [more discussion about time in Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stale/dev/event_time.html#event-time--processing-time--ingestion-time).

Comment: thx for your answer! the problem is just the timestamps, my window is 1 minutes and the actual interval of two continue window is like this:TimeWindow{start=1695780000, end=1695840000}
TimeWindow{start=1695840000, end=1695900000}
TimeWindow{start=1695900000, end=1695960000}

Comment: That clarifies things a bit. Your timestamps are in milliseconds. The first window starts around 19 days past zero, fwiw.

Comment: So what should I do to show correct window time? I try to remove the "*1000" in "element.getTime()*1000", but it still not work...

Comment: The window time comes from the timestamps in the events. You'll have to track down where the event timestamps come from.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem:
due to element.getTime() return a int which represent timestamps, and "element.getTime()*1000" will cause a int overflow, so I could not get the correct timestamps!